# Laravel 5 FatalErrorException Complied.php Class not found

Tags: class, laravel-5

So I'm new to Laravel and started to get the hang of it, but then when I open up a url with http://localhost:8000/properties/create I get this error

FatalErrorException in compiled.php line 7038:Class 'Property' not found

I don't understand why, I have a Property.php in the app directory. Here is my code for the route:

```
use App\Property;

Route::get('properties/create', function() {
$property = new Property;
return View::make('properties.edit')
->with('property', $property)
->with('method', 'post');
});
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: Is the property model name spaced correctly? Where is it saved and can you paste the code?

Comment: may I see what you have in your property.php. pls edit your question